# May we deprecate the [policy] tag?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

Recommend that we deprecate the tag [policy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy) and use the tag [site-policy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-policy) That will enable searching on [site-policy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-policy) to return posts that articulate the policy and culture of H:SE.  That, in turn, will make it easier to refer new users to authoritative reference posts on H:SE policy.

(unless someone can identify a reason to have two overlapping tags. I don't want to maintain questions about policies other than H:SE site policy.)

Unless there is an objection, I'll go through and add [site-policy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-policy) to all questions tagged [policy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy) As time permits, we'll remove the old tag. I've updated the tag wiki.

May need to move this to a second question, but we probably should devise some protocol to identify [site-policy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-policy)  under discussion vs consensus [site-policy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-policy).  Turns out that it is difficult or impossible to remove [discussion](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion).

In the answers below, please comment on the above approach and offer advice on how to manage policy under review vs accepted policy.

- should we create [policy-accepted](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy-accepted) and [policy-review](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy-review)? are dual tagged questions going to confuse search or create other issues?
- Should we just create [policy-discussion](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy-discussion) and remove it after a week of no comments?  Any policy not under discussion is official?
- is there a better way?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. 'Policy' is vague, 'site policy' is clear and relevant.